# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)

Tags: tensorflow, multidimensional-array, keras, tensor

Im facing problem with this line of code in keras with backend Tensorflow 2.0:

```py
loss_out = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(1,))([y_pred, Y_train, X_train_length, label_length])
```

Y_train, X_train_length are `numpy.ndarrays`
y_pred and label_length are class `'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
        tf.convert_to_tensor()
```

example,

```
        import tensorflow as tf
        import numpy as np


        loss = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(1,)) 
                       ([y_pred, Y_train, X_train_length, label_length])
        loss_np = np.asarray(loss, np.float32)

        loss_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(loss_np, np.float32)

        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()  
        print(loss_tf.eval())

        sess.close()
```

Comment: this line  is not getting executed. Geeting value error: not able to convert numpy array to tensor                                                                                                                         
         loss = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(1,)) 
                       ([y_pred, Y_train, X_train_length, label_length])

Comment: @neena yeah what in that line? Can you elaborate your question or issue.

Comment: this line [loss = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(1,)) ([y_pred, Y_train, X_train_length, label_length])] is not getting executed.                                                                          
     Getting value error: not able to convert numpy array to tensor

Comment: actually i just wrote loss not (loss_out) so change it according what you have written in your code.

Comment: I tried this:  loss_out = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(1,))([tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred, np.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(Y_train, np.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train_length, np.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(label_length, np.float32)])                                                Now getting error : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: @neena i knew only this method but there are many other methods out there too you can check and i will also check if i will find anything

Answer (score 0):

You can create dummy inputs

```
# you have defined the rest of your graph somewhere here

Y_train = Input(shape=...)
X_train_length = Input(shape=...)

loss = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(1,)
              )([y_pred, Y_train, X_train_length, label_length])

# defining the model is slightly different with multiple inputs
training_model = Model(inputs=[image_input, Y_train, X_train_length], outputs=[loss])
```

And when you want to train your model you will pass the parameter `x` as a list of length 3, such as

```
x = [<images - np.ndarray shape (batch, h, w, c)>, <Y_train inputs - np.ndarray>,
     <X_train_length inputs - np.ndarray>]
```

And of course dummy values for `y`

```
y = np.zeros((batch, 1))
```

And it's never been simpler finally than `training_model.train_on_batch(x, y)`

Alternatively make a generator that generates `x` and `y` in the form described above and use `training_model.fit_generator(data_generator)`